# Does Apache Directory support computer Entry?

Tags: apache-ds

I want to create a complex Apache Directory Server with all components that i can, so i have a question if i can create a entity(entry) in ApacheDs of type computer like in Active Directory or Apache support only Users and Group?

Answer (score 3):

If it does not contain a schema that meets your needs, you can add schema elements. So, if it doesn't have a "computer object" schema element already, you can just add that.

Here's the documentation: https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/2.3.1-adding-schema-elements.html

I do not know whether it contains built-in schema elements for managing computer objects, but it does support more than "Users and Groups".

Comment: do you know where i can find info about all build-in schema elements?

Comment: There seems to be a pretty decent amount of information in the site I linked.